# How do I recreate "on pin pressed" for pins other than 0-3 in micro:bit makecode?

Tags: bbc-microbit

Micro:bit has a code blocks editor which has a few blocks for its pins.

The main three pins (accessible by alligator clip) can be used in a function "on pin pressed."  The function will send a single trigger response if a pin is pressed less than 1 second and is debounced.

For any of the other pins, this function is not available.

Therefore I must emulate similar functionality using other available blocks.  I'm currently using the "set pull pin" and "on pin pulse" blocks, but it's not debounced at all.  Image below:

[image]

Note: I've tried every iteration of high/low for pull and pulse.

I'm not sure if my approach is the best one either.  In short, **How do I recreate "on pin pressed" for pins other than 0-3 in micro:bit makecode?**  In general, how does one use the GPIO pins (other than 0-3) as buttons?

If you want to test out the code-editor, you can do so here:  https://makecode.microbit.org/#editor

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the micro:bit can only use the pins that have ADC functionality for resistive touch . Information about what functionality is available on what pins is available at:
https://makecode.microbit.org/device/pins

And ADC is needed because resistive sensing detects a flow of current from the pin that is touched to the GND pin. Your body needs a connection to GND (either by touching it or by connecting a wire from it to your clothing) while you touch the input pin to complete a circuit between the two pins.

The circuit you are creating is a potential divider where your body is a variable resistor changing the voltage on the pin you are touching.
Some more information about this type of circuit at:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zk37hyc/revision/8
The pull up resistor would be like R1 in the diagram on that page and your body would be the variable resistor R2.

It is using Ohms Law which there is more information about at:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z8b2pv4/revision/1

If you to use P4, it is also used to control the LED screen on the micro:bit so you would have to turn that off.

If you do the code below you should hear the effect of the resistance changing when you touch P4

[image]